# Reassign name after .remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button to generate elements:

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Elements</a>
<div id="p_scents">
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt" /></label>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt"  name="p_scnt_' + i +'" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
```

For example after clicks i have:

```
<div id="p_scents">

<input type="text" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt_1">         
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt_2">
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt_3">     

</div>
```

After remove p_scnt_2 i have p_scnt_1 and p_scnt_3, I need to reorder as p_scnt_1 and p_scnt_2

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/

Comment: The `.live()` API has been deprecated for many years.

Comment: And using the same `id` value on more than one element is invalid.

Comment: This question ("how do I renumber elements?") has been asked and answered. Please be sure to search thoroughly before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: See answers on the linked question (and probably several others). The only difference in your case is you're setting the `name` attribute instead of `value`. (And you're using jQuery, which may make it easier with [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).)